# React Native function bind() [Function bound ]

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and am having difficulty returning the  value passed by textField following the react native documentation. What am i doing wrong?
 this is the return and this way I can not validate in API the values
entered. LOG  {"cpf": [Function bound ], "email": [Function bound ]}

```
    export default class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                email: '',
                cpf: '',
                error: '',
            }
            this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this)
            this.handleCpf = this.handleCpf.bind(this)
        }

        handleEmail = (e) => {
            const newValue = e.currentTarget.value
            this.setState({ value: newValue })

        }
        handleCpf = (e) => {
            const newValue = e.currentTarget.value
            this.setState({ value: newValue })

        }

        handleRota = async (data) => {
            try {


            } catch (error) {

        }

        handleLogin = async () => {
            try {


            } catch (error) {

            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View
                    style={styles.mContainer}
                >
                    <View
                        style={styles.inputEmail}
                    >
                        <TextField
                            label="Digite seu Email"
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={this.handleEmail}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View
                        style={styles.inputCpf}
                    >
                        <TextField
                            label="Digite seu CPF"
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            value={this.state.cpf}
                            onChange={this.handleCpf}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <RaisedTextButton
                            style={styles.btnDefault}
                            title="Acessar"
                            onPress={this.handleLogin}
                            color={TextField.defaultProps.tintColor}
                            titleColor='white'
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

can help me?

Comment: There is no reason to use `bind` at all with the syntax you are using. Remove the `bind` calls.

Comment: Yes my friend but I received one warning. look

setUpDeveloperTools.js:73 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.

Comment: * Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: 
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `handleEmail` twice, as a property in the constructor and as a method after.

Remove `this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this)` from the constructor and move it to the `TextField`, like this:

```js
// ...

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    email: '',
    cpf: '',
    error: '',
  }
}

// ...

<TextField
   label="Digite seu Email"
   autoCapitalize="none"
   autoCorrect={false}
   value={this.state.email}
   onChange={this.handleEmail.bind(this)}
/>

// ...
```

Same for `handleCpf`

Also, the value of the `TextField` is in `e.text` not in `e.currentTarget.value`, [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange) is the documentation.

Alternatively, you can use `onChangeText`, that gives you the value directly, for example:

```js
<TextField
   // ...
   onChangeText={this.handleEmail.bind(this)}
/>

// ...

handleEmail = (newValue) => {
  this.setState({ email: newValue })
}

//...

handleLogin = () => {
  console.log(this.state.email)
}
```

Comment: Hello, @bug I try u suggestion but not a success.
the return is undefined because the "value" of "e.currentTarget.value" is not exists.
for log this event I found "e.nativeEvent.text" that returned the value TextField.
BEFORE 
handleEmail = (e) => {
            const newValue = e.currentTarget.value
            this.setState({ value: newValue })
        }
AFTER
handleEmail = (e) => {
        const newValue = e.nativeEvent.text
        const value = this.setState({ value: newValue })
        console.log('value newValue: ',newValue)
    }
LOG  value newValue:  rod@gmail.com

Comment: My new question is how I will pass the value of TextField to variable "data". Because I couldn't pass. the return is  LOG  handleLogin {"cpf": [Function anonymous], "email": [Function anonymous]}.

can I help?

handleLogin = async (e) => {
        try {
            let data = {
                email: this.handleEmail,
                cpf: this.handleCpf
            }
            console.log('handleLogin', data)

Comment: You are storing the value of the field into the state with `this.setState` so you can get it back from inside `handleLogin` with `this.state.value`, just replace `value` with something unique and more meaningful because at the moment you are using `value` for both fields

Comment: I've included handleLogin in the answer